# PageBlockTable inlineEdit - save issue

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, pageblock, pageblocktable, inline

I have VF page where I have displayed Contact information in pageBlockSection with mode="inlineEdit" as below..

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactDetailController" tabStyle="My_Contacts__tab" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!contact.name}" mode="inlineEdit" html-style="background-color: white;!important;">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveContact}" value="Save" reRender="contact" status="loading" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelChanges}" value="Cancel" reRender="contact" status="loading" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Information" columns="3" html-style="white-space:nowrap;!important; background-color: white;!important;" id="contact">
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Name}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.DoNotCall}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.AssistantName}" />
                ..............
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I have written save method in my extension controller 'ContactDetailController' as below

```
public Pagereference saveContact() {
    // contact = (Contact) sController.getRecord();
    upsert sController.getRecord();    
    return null;
}
public Pagereference cancelChanges() {    
    sController.reset();
    return null;
}
```

The issue I am facing is , The value I edit is getting saved only if I click somewhere else in the page before clicking save button. If I edit a value and click on 'Save' button without clicking anywhere , values are not getting persisted.

This occurs even in pageBlockTable with inlineEdit. But in a Standard SFDC page I see it working properly. How to get it working in my VF page also?

Comment: Not sure if you are still having an issue, but I found your question when working on a similar issue here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40930/inline-editing-error-value-cannot-exceed-0-characters/76261#76261.